# Apply chained filters on a collection

Tags: scala

I have a sequence of a scala class instances -

```
val vehicles = Seq[Vehicle]

class Vehicle(name:String, model:String, age:Int, color:String )
{...}
```

Now I need to pass this sequence through a chain of filters - each filtering for a specific attribute.

```
List[Vehicle].filter(_.name.startsWith("J")).filter(_.model.contains("Toy:)).....
```

Since each of these filter conditions are complex , I need to encapsulate them in a function.

Is there a way in scala to apply a custom function on a collection viz `List[Vehicle].applyfilterchain(params)` , to return the final filtered collection.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great excercise for [*"playing type-tetris"*](https://underscore.io/blog/posts/2017/04/11/type-tetris.html).

So, we want to apply multiple predicates to all elements of a list, so that gives the signature of the function.

```scala
def filterChain[A](list: List[A])(predicates: List[A => Boolean]): List[A]
```

> This is possible because in **Scala** functions are just normal values, so we can have a `List` of them.

Now, for the implementation, there are two routes we may follow.

1. Iterate the predicates, applying them to the list one by one.
2. Iterate the list once, applying all predicates to the same element.

Both are applicable, but a quick complexity analysis shows is better to do the second one.

> The implementation of the first one is left as an exercise for the reader.
> **Hint**: Use `foldLeft`.

Thus, we know we want to start our implementation using `filter` on the `List`.

```scala
def filterChain[A](list: List[A])(predicates: List[A => Boolean]): List[A] =
  list.filter(a => ???)
```

Now, we know the body of the lambda has to return a `Boolean`.
We also know that we have `a` of type `A`, and `predicates` of type `List[A => Boolean]`
Thus, we know we may apply each function inside `predicates` to `a`, and then we want to know if all succeded. That is exactly what `forall` allows.

```scala
a => predicates.forall(predicate => predicate(a))
```

Putting it all together: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/W5k9KCZKRj6XN71tompZfw/6

Answer (score 0):

It can be implemented as a regular method:

```scala
def applyfilterchain(params...)(seq: Seq[Vehicle]) = {
  seq.filter(...).filter(...)
}

// And then:
applyfilterchain(...)(vehicles)
```

Or if you really want to, you can define it as an extension method (also called implicit class in Scala 2) so that it can be called like the following: `vehicles.applyfilterchain(...)`.